# Can't spin up Composer env in Australian zone: "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unexpected location: australia-southeast1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create my Composer env in the Australian region. But I keep getting the following error:

> "INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unexpected location: australia-southeast1"

Using the following command:

```
gcloud beta composer environments create airflow-test-environment -- 
location australia-southeast1 --zone australia-southeast1-a --m
achine-type n1-standard-1 --labels env=beta
```

Spinning it up in the US works fine.

Is there a restriction on the regions that Composer can be spun up in that I've missed in the docs somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, `location` may be only set to `us-central1` or `europe-west1`. Only these two are supported for now.

See https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/gcloud-installation#setting_the_default_project_and_location_in_your_local_client

Comment: @GrahamPolley in here https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/environment-configuration-parameters#required_parameters it states more clearly:"The beta release supports us-central1 and europe-west1. " for location parameter.

Comment: Thanks guys. Is Australia on the roadmap?

Comment: It's still not possible to file a PIT for Composer (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), it should be possible soon. At that time feel free to open a Feature Request so that the composer team can take it into consideration.

Comment: i am having same `INVALID_ARGUMENT` error, for using `asia-northeast1-b` where can I get help or when will it be done?

Comment: In case anyone comes across this, you can find which regions support which products [here](https://cloud.google.com/about/locations)